# Is it possible to send arrays from bash to C++ program?

Tags: bash, c++

I wanted to know, if its possible to create an array_of_strings and send it to a C++ program, which has an argument string array_of_strings[]?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Gilles's answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/48958/9785) gives you 90% of it, but the rest is on bash to do right.

```
$ arr=(foo bar 'Hello World!')
$ ./foo "${arr[@]}"
```

Answer (score 2):

All programs receive an array of strings as its arguments. In C++, the arguments are the `argv` parameter of the `main` function. The first element of that array is the name of the program, the others are the arguments that you pass.

```
$ cat foo.cpp
#include <iostream>
int main (int argc, char *argv[]) {
    for (int i = 1; i < argc; i++)
        std::cout << argv[i] << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
$ g++ -o foo foo.cpp
$ ./foo hello world
hello
world
```

Comment: I wanted to mean, not writing it explicitly, rather save strings in a bash array, and send it to a C++ function.